# How to remove text between a delimiter and whitespace or punctuation?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a JavaScript array of strings with synonyms indicated by a caret. Examples as follows:

- `I'm baffled^bemused by his decision.`
- `"Why are you so mean^nasty?" she wailed^moaned.`

I want to return:

- `I'm baffled by his decision.`
- `"Why are you so mean?" she wailed.`

This `/\^([^^]*)\./` works for single punctuation marks, but I haven't been able to get it to function for `[.,:;?"' ]`. I'm grateful for help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to search and replace with the empty string using this regex:

```
\^([^^]*?)(?=[.,:;?"' ])
```

You can see which portions you will be replacing, as well as a detailed visual of what's going on with the regex, on [www.debuggex.com](http://www.debuggex.com/?re=%5C%5E%28%5B%5E%5E%5D%2a?%29%28?=%5B.,%3a;?%22%27%20%5D%29&str=I%27m%20baffled%5Ebemused%20by%20his%20decision.%0D%0A%22Why%20are%20you%20so%20mean%5Enasty?%22%20she%20wailed%5Emoaned.).

Comment: Thanks. This works a treat; the link is useful too. Thanks also to the other contributors.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var str = "Why are you so mean^nasty?";
var regex = /\^\w+/;

var result = str.replace(regex, '');

console.log(result); //"Why are you so mean?"
```

[See it working here](http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=%5C%5E%5Cw%2b&input=Why%20are%20you%20so%20mean%5Enasty?%0AI%27m%20baffled%5Ebemused%20by%20his%20decision.%0Ashe%20wailed%5Emoaned.)

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a String.replace with the the empty string.

You want to match a '^' followed by all of the non-space characters until the next space, so the regex would be

```
\^[^\s]+
```

EDIT: As pointed out in the comments, this doesn't adjust for punctuation.

```
\^\w+
```

Ought to work, as \w matches all "word" characters, i.e., a-z, A-Z, 0-9, & _

Comment: I suspect you need to adjust to account for punctuation